# SSH for DOS / Win 3.1

Tags: ms-dos, windows-3.x, software-recommendation

Is there an SSH client for DOS 6.22 or Windows 3.1 that supports certificates and could be used to connect to AWS or Azure instances, or any other server for that matter? I have another laptop restoration I'm hoping to finish this week, want to find a cool purpose for it rather than just sit there and gather dust.

Comment: There's [sshdos](http://sshdos.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I've seen it, but does it support latest security requirements? Does it handle ppk/pems?

Comment: What are the specs of the laptop?  I once set up Linux on a '386 SX with 2 MB of RAM once so it could be used as a dumb SSH terminal, so you may have better luck with an old version of Linux (or FreeBSD) and a new version of SSH.

Comment: Debian 1.0 was the earliest I've seen someone running on such laptop. There is no support for it anymore, it's a 16bit 20mhz 386sx, 3mb ram

Comment: It doesn't need to be supported, it's not like MS-DOS or Windows 3.1 is still supported either.  You just need to be able to build a newer SSH for it.

Comment: A 386SX will take *ages* to perform the calculations required for a certificate-based connection using current algorithms. You’d probably be better off using it as a plain telnet client to another system which can connect using SSH to the target.

Comment: So in theory I could fit a RPi0W, connect telnet between C386 and RPi and then from RPi hop onto cloud?

Comment: @BartekMalysz Not in theory - just do it.  You will most likely need to enable telnet separately on the pi.

Comment: But then, why use the laptop at all, if the RPi can be the terminal on itself? How about any other purpose, like playing "Day of the Tentacle" or similar? ;-)

Comment: I have other machines for gaming, just thought it would be cool to be able to work from an old machine. I like the keybaord, I like the looks plus think of a look on people's faces when you pull out a commodore laptop to do some modern work. Priceless ;)

Comment: @BartekMalysz Can the machine run any kind of Unix - a Linux variant, OpenBSD, NetBSD or FreeBSD (or others)?

Answer (score 6):

How about SSH2DOS?

> SSH2DOS v0.2.1+SHA256.1 patch by Antti Takala
> https://github.com/AnttiTakala/SSH2DOS Released on 04-14-2021
>
> The aim was to update the ciphers and protocols to more 2021 standards
> so the programs would be usable with current ssh servers without the
> need to change the server configuration to allow less secure
> connection methods.

https://github.com/AnttiTakala/SSH2DOS/

Comment: The readme also says: `Note that the random number generator used in the program is not cryptographically secure at all. There may also be other security issues
so USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.` Though depending on the use case this may also not be a serious issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you could use Java on Windows 3.1 there is a SSH client written in pure Java that would work. I use one on a desktop Java system that has been running for 12 years on Windows to avoid having an SSH tunnel. If it works on an old version of Java that still runs on 3.1 is another question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java

Comment: The commenters above worry that modern crypto may be too hard for *native* code on retro hardware, and you’re proposing to add JVM overhead on top of that?